# What statistics should I use for evaluating the accuracy of predictions?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, r-squared, intraclass-correlation, predictor

I have two variables representing 1) players' predicted fantasy football points and 2) players' actual fantasy football points scored.  What statistics are best for assessing the accuracy of the predictions in terms of absolute agreement (not just relative rank-order accuracy) in relation to the actual values?  I'd like to compare the accuracy of various sources of projections.  The predicted and actual values are both continuous.  I'm considering statistics like: r-squared, Harrell's c-index, and ICC (absolute agreement).  Which statistic(s) would you recommend and why?

I'd like to use R (and any necessary packages) to compute the prediction accuracy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself first "why am I making predictions?". If you are trying to predict something, it usually means you (or someone you advise) are intending to take some action based on that prediction. Therefore you need to ask yourself what is most important for your application? Different measures of accuracy are derived using different assumptions about the data, models and the utility of the predictions. In order to determine which one is best for your situation, you first need to think about these questions as they apply to you, then carefully look into the rationale behind different measures of accuracy to see which might apply.

If you re-formulate your question to give people more information, that might help to get some specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I have re-formulated the question with more specifics of my data.

Answer (score 1):

You're going down the wrong track talking about "agreement". Things like ICC have to do with raters, not predictors. I'd recommend a [paper by frequent-contributor Rob Hyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/foresight.pdf) to you.

I've edited this since my previous answer referred to MAD but non-thinkingly pointed you to the wikipedia page referring to MAD as a measure of spread in a univariate series. What I meant was MAD as in Mean Absolute Deviation, which is more clearly known as MAE (Mean Absolute Error). Cursed acronyms!

Are you doing this by hand, or using Excel, R, or some kind of package to do it?

Comment: Thanks, Wayne.  I will examine the MAD, as you suggested.  I also found a very helpful guide for evaluating forecast accuracy from the following online textbook: http://otexts.com/fpp/2/5/

Comment: @dadrivr: MAD is just a robust measure of dispersion, and you have several options. As Bogdanovist mentions, you have to decide what you're actually measuring and how errors are counted. For example, if you calculate the average absolute difference between players' predictions and outcomes, you're assuming all games count the same. You could also weight some games more than others. Or penalize predictions that are higher than the actual score more than those that are lower. It's not necessarily a cookie-cutter solution.

Comment: That makes sense.  The predictions are for the full season (not game-by-game).  Is there a good resource that discusses the different options for evaluating predictions, and what their uses are?  I think I'm particularly interested in two estimates: 1) overall accuracy (weighting players equally) and 2) penalizing predictions that are higher than the actual score more than those that are lower.  Any practical guidance here would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how I would compute MAD with two vectors (one vector is predicted values for each player and the second vector is the actual values for each player).  It appears the R function, mad(), only takes one vector, presumably because MAD calculates the dispersion for a single vector of numbers.  Thus, I don't see how I'd apply MAD to my example where I'm examining how close in value one vector is to a second vector.

Comment: Your edit was very helpful, Wayne.  I am using R to evaluate the predictions.  I came across the accuracy() function of the forecast package, which calculates mean absolute error (MAE), root mean squared error (RMSE), and mean absolute percentage error (MAPE).  Do you know any R functions that calculate mean absolute scaled error (MASE), as recommended by Hyn­d­man and Koehler (2006)?  Thanks so much!

Comment: accuracy() also computes MASE.

Comment: I don't receive MASE from the accuracy() function when providing 2 vectors (actual and predicted values).  It appears that the accuracy() function computes MASE when computing a forecast from a time series.  My data are not a time series, however.  Is there a way to calculate MASE from 2 vectors: actual and predicted?

Comment: The MASE requires the historical data to compute the scaling factor. If you only give the actual numbers and forecast numbers to accuracy(), it can't compute the MASE. The MASE is defined for time series and non-time series data.